# What is a minimum SQL Server role allowing trigger creation/dropping?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, security-roles

**Prerequisite:**

There is client/server application written in Delphi32. The RDBMS is SQL Server 2005. A certain application functionality requires creation/dropping of triggers (from the application using ad hoc DDL statements) in the target database.

**Problem:**

If a user belongs to roles sysadmin there is no problem to create/drop triggers. However, this is considered to be a too permissive role for an application user.

**Questions:**

- What is the standard minimum (i.e. most restrictive) SQL Server role that could be used for creation/dropping of triggers?
- Would creation of a custom role, rather than using standard ones, constitute a more fine-grain approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Please don't use the `mssql` tag; use `sql-server` instead. Same with "MSSQL" in a title or in the body of your question or answer, since the product is called "SQL Server". It's a lot easier to find in a search if it's named correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various options depending on the scope of the grant (any trigger in a database, any in a schema or a specific table).

Generally the permissions required for a SQL operation are documented in the SQL reference. E.g. for `CREATE TRIGGER` on SQL 2008 see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189799) (scroll down to "Permissions"), in this case:

> DML trigger requires ALTER persmission on the table or view on which the trigger is to be created

You can create a role granted just the permissions you want and then add users/groups to that role, so the minimum role is one you create with just the specific access you want to allow its members.